# Web slices not loading in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, ie8-webslice

I'm trying to add a webslice to a site i admin, but for some reason i cant get any webslices at all to work in ie8. I have tried 2 different machine at home and one at work but i hit the same problem, i just get an 'ie cannot display this page' error.

If i hit the diagnose problem button i get a script debug error:

Line: 264
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

I get exactly the same error on every different slice, even down to the line number. Anyone any ideas?

Edit - By a webslice i am talking about new functionality that came with ie that lets you ad part of a webpage (say the div containing news) to your links bar. The when you click on the slice it expands to show you the content of the slice. More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304073(VS.85).aspx">http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304073(VS.85).aspx

Cheers
Luke

Comment: You may need to add some context so people can figure out what a webslice is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally managed to find the answer! There seems to be a bug with the full version of ie and google gears. If you disable the gears ie add on they work again! - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969213

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0811052

It's a pretty down-and-dirty explanation of how to make them. My guess is that you're just not formatting them right...

Good luck!

Comment: Hi Jason,
I thought it was this as well but slices from other sites wont load either. Ill have to use wireshark or something to try and work out what's going on